# How do I do a Client side sort of a DataTable using LINQ

Tags: linq, gridview, sorting, datatable

How do I sort a DataTable on the client side using LINQ? (Server side sorting is not supported with my data store)

I was doing something like this which doesn't work

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> dr = GetDataTableData().AsEnumerable();

           if (sortDirection == "Ascending")
                        {
                            dr = dr.OrderBy(x => sortExpression);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dr = dr.OrderByDescending(x => sortExpression);
                        }

                GridView1.DataSource = dr;
                GridView1.DataBind();
```

But I dont see the gridview sorting at all, what am I missing here?

Comment: To clafify: you are talking about WebForms, right?

Comment: In what way does it not work? More details, please.

Comment: @chris GridView's expression used to sort, sop when you click on a gridview column, it brings back the name of that column (e.SortExpression)

@jeff yes

Comment: @Jay I dont see any sorting on the GridView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that sortExpression is a string that you are passing in to the method; You should be sorting on something in x.  eg:

```
dr = dr.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName);
```

As Rory pointed out in the comments, you can just use x[sortExpression] in your case; If you were using objects instead of the DataRow, you could make a key selector expression and pass it in to OrderBy() instead; something like:

```
Func<IDataRow, string> sortExpressionReal = x => x["FirstName"].ToString();
```

then your OrderBy would look like:

```
dr = dr.OrderBy(sortExpressionReal);
```

Comment: Yes, sortExpression is the gridrow header the user clicks on for ex: "FirstName", How do I map that to X.FirstName?

Comment: you could just use a linq data source and let the framework take care of it for you.  Otherwise you have to write your own mapping from the values passed in to the event.

Comment: Since x is a DataRow instance, you can use "x[sortExpression]" or "x.Field<TypeOfField>(sortExpression)". You will need to import the System.Data.Linq namespace to use the second version, and TypeOfField might be a problem if the fields contain different data types, the first option is easiest because it'll just treat everything as object.

Comment: Ok I tried this: dr = dr.OrderBy(x => x[sortExpression]);

didnt work...still get unsorted data

Comment: Did you update both your OrderBy and OrderByDescending?  Maybe "Ascending" isn't what you are actually getting for sortDirection?

Comment: @Chris, I tried your new updated suggestions, still no sort :(

Comment: Based on the code you have here and this update, you really should be seeing a sorted list.  My only other thought is falling back to standard webforms issues; Are you possibly double-binding the list (eg, sorted bind is occurring in GridView_Sort() and an unsorted bind is occurring in Page_PreRender())?

Comment: Yes Yes Yes...Let me try change that.

Comment: Quickest/easiest way would be to make sure in Page_PreRender() to only bind the gridview when !IsPostback.  Alternatively, you could bind the sorted list in Page_PreRender and change GridView_Sort() so instead of binding it just sets a couple properties so PreRender knows how to sort the data.

Comment: Thank Chris! Great Debugging :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use linq. You can do this quite easily with DataViews
DataView vw = new DataView(dtbl,"filter","FirstName DESC",DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
GridView1.DataSource=vw;
GridView1.DataBind();